# $(elem).html() = localStorage does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

My options.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Notifier v1.0.2</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cowboy's Item Notifyer</h1>
    <label>Last updated hat:<h2 id='itemname'>[ loading... ]</h2></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Then my options.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#itemname').html() = localStorage.mostRecentHat;
});
```

It's supposed to change the innerHTML from `[ loading... ]` to the value of `mostRecentHat` but it turns up the value as undefined and doesnt change the innerHTML.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the value as a parameter to `html` method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#itemname').html(localStorage.mostRecentHat);
    // document.getElementById('itemname').innerHTML = localStorage.mostRecentHat;
});
```